# SQL concatenate one of the columns

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, listagg

I have the following output:

```
portfolio name | accounts | segment | number
A | USD | seg1 | 23
A | CNY | seg2 | null
A | EUR | seg2 | null
B | EUR | seg2 | null
B | USD | seg2 | null
B | EUR | seg3 | 24
```

And I would like to basically concatenate all the rows according to portfolio name, same segment and same number. As you can see sometimes number can be null as well.

Basically the end output i want for this example is:

```
A | USD | seg1 | 23
A | CNY, EUR | seg2 | null
B | EUR, USD | seg2 | null
B | EUR | seg3 | 24
```

I've tried using listagg but can't figure it out...

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: At least some of them support the ANSI SQL `||` concatenation.

Comment: Your output does not seem to logically follow the input.

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the mentioning of `listagg()`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry amended my example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle (You said you tried to use `LISTAGG`) then :

```
SELECT t.portfolio_name, t.segment, 
       LISTAGG(COALESCE(t.accounts,''),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.accounts) as segments,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(COALESCE(s.number,''),',') WITHIN GROUP  (ORDER BY s.number) 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT p.portfolio_name,p.segment,p.number
              FROM YourTable p) s
        WHERE t.portfolio_name = s.portfolio_name
          AND t.segment = s.segment ) as numbers
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.portfolio_name, t.segment
```

Comment: Thank you this is almost perfect. Is there any way to make numbers only include distinct values?

Comment: @user3438447 You should update your example to show what you want here.

Comment: the numbers column now contains duplicates. example: ACC123,ACC123,ACC123 etc. And in the case that the number column was null it's  , , , , etc. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: This code contains many error + its logic is way more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Why the `COALESCE(<column>,'')`? You're effectively saying "when <column> is null, then output null" since Oracle doesn't have the concept of an empty string

Comment: Because I wasn't sure what happens when one of the values are null. Also, I wrote it before I notices its Oracle, that's why its COALESCE and not NVL:).

Comment: (1) the syntax is "WITHIN GROUP" and not just "GROUP" (2) number is a keyword therefore should be "number" (3) assuming "number" is numeric then `COALESCE(s.number,'')` will yield an error since the 2 operand types are different. And as for the logic, the OP requested "concatenate all the rows according to portfolio name, same segment and same number" so group by this columns answer the request.

Comment: 1) Typo . 2) it was an edit and I have added it through my mobile, so I skipped the aliases which avoids it . 3) I assume it's not, since it hadn't . 4) Read the comments, it's not what he wanted, the query was a lot simpler at the beggining. @dudumarkovitz

Comment: Exactly what I gave him, a list of accounts and a list of distincted numbers grouped by portfolio and segment. @dudumarkovitz

Answer (score 0):

```
select          "portfolio name"
               ,listagg (accounts,',') within group (order by accounts) as accounts
               ,segment
               ,"number"

from            t

group by        "portfolio name"
               ,segment
               ,"number"
;
```

Answer (score -1):

If columns are fixed the concat all columns but make sure that the for this output you need to convert null as  string.
For example:
        Select c1+'|'+cast(c2 as varchar) from t1

Comment: Your answer doesn't appear to relate to what the OP is asking for.